# django forms get value from cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-forms

How to make django forms get value from cookies? I save user previuos input to cookies and if user opens form again I want to show that values.

Now I do forms manually like this:

```
<select name="transmission_type" class="selectpicker">
    <option value="" selected>Select value</option>
    {% for transmission in transmissions %}
    {% if transmission == request.COOKIES.transmission %}
    <option value="{{ transmission.id }}" selected>{{transmission }}</option>
    {% else %}
    <option value="{{ transmission.id }}">{{transmission }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

How I could do this in django forms?

Comment: One option that might work for you is to save the information to the session. Inside your view, in ```get_context_data()``` set ```self.request.session['temp_info'] = info_to_store```. Then you can reference that in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by myself. You just need to use django forms initial attribute for your form in views.

Solution example:

```
if 'something' in request.COOKIES:
    something = request.COOKIES['something']
else:
    something = ''


form = SomethingForm(initial={'something': something })
```