# How to retrieve a cookie in Django/Wagtail to set Python variable

Tags: jquery, python, django, cookies, wagtail

I am building a website that will have some different content depending on what province a user is coming from. I have set up a modal window using jQuery/Bootstrap to pop up when the user lands on the site if there is no cookie set:

**base.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (Cookies.get('province') == null) {
     $('#provinceModal').modal('show');
    }

    $('button#ontario').click(function() {
        Cookies.set('province', 'ontario');
        $('#provinceModal').modal('hide');
    });
    $('button#alberta').click(function() {
        Cookies.set('province', 'alberta');
        $('#provinceModal').modal('hide');
    });
    $('button#quebec').click(function() {
        Cookies.set('province', 'quebec');
        $('#provinceModal').modal('hide');
    });
  });
</script>
```

The cookies are being set correctly, as I can see them in the browser after one of the buttons is clicked. The problem I'm having is with retrieving the cookie using Python. I want to save the province variable and then display certain content using if statements (depending on what the province is equal to).

I've tried this and I am able to print the cookie to the console:

**cookies.py**

```
import Cookie
import os
import requests


def get_cookies():
    s = requests.session()
    r = s.get("http://www.twitter.com")

    cookie =  r.cookies['_twitter_sess']

    return cookie
```

How do I pass this value to a variable in Python to be used in a template? I'm not sure what I should do next. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem using template tags.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def get_cookies(context, value1, value2):
    request = context['request']
    result = request.COOKIES.get('province', '')
    return result
```

I am able to find the province cookie value this way and use it in my template like so:

```
{% if request.COOKIES.province == 'ontario' %}
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

This seems to be the simplest way to achieve the functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the Python Cookie module, rather than the django ones set by the HttpRequest object, as [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735467/django-forms-get-value-from-cookies).  (Now out of date, but read on!)

In your view that's processing the backend of that JQuery popup (presumably you're sending it to an endpoint in Django and that code is a snippet from your view), you want to use 
the [request.session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) documents to check and set the status of your cookies.

In a Django view, for example, it looks like this:

```
def a_standard_view(request):
    print request.session
```

You can go on to check if cookie setting is playing nicely, by using (again, this was in the section I originally linked):

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def faux_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            return HttpResponse("You're logged in.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Please enable cookies and try again.")
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    return render(request, 'foo/login_form.html')
```

In your particular instance,  you will need an endpoint (so /ajax/province/ or similar) that handles your jquery.  Your Jquery will need to use the [get call to hit that endpoin](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)t with whatever details you're trying to store in your session data.

Comment: I have updated my question to include my latest attempt using requests.session. I am able to get a cookie from twitter.com (although I'm having trouble retrieving from localhost, but I have read that that can be a problem). I am able to print the cookie to the console, but I'm not sure how to pass it to Python so that I can use it as a variable within a template. Help?

Comment: Are you trying to use cookies *that you set*, or are you trying to get cookies that *another site sets on your machine*?  Your question indicates the former, but you're asking about the latter.

Comment: I am ultimately trying to get the cookie that I set in the browser with my jQuery code above. I am unable to retrieve that and I read that it could be because it doesn't work well with localhost. I was able to retrieve a cookie from Twitter, however, so I *think* I'm on the right track?

Comment: No, you're doing different things.  When you do wget you're going out and using the requests library to retrieve a webpage.  That sets a cookie on your machine, just like it would visiting in a browser.  In one of *your* existing python views, go in and print out the contents of request.session (that I linked in the docs above), and then visit the URL for that view.

Comment: Worth saying - you want the Django requests object, not the general python requests library. Every Django view has a requests object attached to it as the first variable - that's what you're using.  Just going to update the answer.

Comment: I have found another solution that I am going to use. I have posted it below. Thanks so much for your help!